# Loading PHP page with Javascript variable

Tags: javascript, php, android, webview

First let me introduce my environment. I'm developing a webapp that runs inside Android app (webview) developed by other people. This app is configured with store ID and the URL of my webapp. Each store can only set the ID, not URL.

The webapp will be placed in different stores so it needs to be loaded with correct store information each time it reloads (store name, contact info...).

Here comes my problem: web app is built with PHP, and the method they told me to use to get store ID from the Android app is javascript. For example:

```
<script>
 Android.getStoreID();
</srcript>
```

This method returns store id as integer. I'm retrieving all store details from an API (some details gets updated every day) in json, specifying the store ID when calling the API.

The ideal is to run the javascript method, get store ID, and pass it to php to get all store info and displaying it in the home page.

I already read all about "*PHP runs in server side, javascript client side...*" and tried to run the script, reload the page with correct id (by URL parameter) but it didn't work on production.

```
var storeid = Android.getStoreid();
var parameter = "http://localhost/wordpress/?id="+storeid;
if (window.location.href !== parameter) {
 window.location.href="?id="+storeid; }
```

Any idea or orientation? I read maybe some jquery or ajax can help?

Comment: What is the value of "storeid" when you run it? Try to debug it, add a console.log(storeid); and then open browser's console to see it. Also, do you see any other error message using the console?

Comment: This is another problem I did not mention: the webview of the app is not enabled to be debugged. I made a test.html page to test the javascript method and works: returns for example "185" integer. Using the metodology I describe (URL parameter) the app enters in a loop reloading and reloading. In my computer (without Android method obviously) the URL parameters worked well. Note that is Android kitkat 4.4, without the updated webview from Play Store.

Comment: It loops because the window.location.href is different from the parameter, if you could also log the values of these two you can find what is wrong. I hope you haven't entered the url parameter hardcoded like above.

Comment: You when you try and try and you see always same code...? Thank you, after debugging a bit... I saw that I left localhost URL there. Now works perfectly!

Comment: I'm glad that I helped you ;)